# Evaluate the Triple Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use cylindrical coordinates to evaluate the triple integral $\iiint_E (x^2+y^2)dV$, where $E$ is the solid bounded by the circular paraboloid $z=16−4(x^2+y^2)$ and the $xy$-plane.

This is Homework. I dont know what to do. Please help so I can understand. Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know how to convert from Cartesian to cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: As @AméricoTavares suggests, can you express each of $x$, $y$, and $z$ in terms of $r$, $\theta$, and $z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

1. You want to express your region in terms of cylindrical coordinates $r, \theta, z$. That will determine the bounds of the integral.
2. Use $x = r\sin \theta, y = r\cos \theta$ to convert $x^2+y^2$ to $r,\theta,z$ as well.
3. Use $dV = rdrd\theta dz$ and integrate.